# Stored procedures and UDF's Oracle vs SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, function

First thanks for any help that is offered. I'm a complete SQL Server newbie, working solely with Oracle and PL/SQL for the last 20 years.

Any relevant documentation I could be pointed too would be great, as my current sources haven't yet supplied answers!

Is the following true: Oracle Function = SQL Server User Defined Function
                       Oracle Procedure = SQL Server SPROC?

My simplified Oracle example:

```
select student_id
       ,someschema.f_get_accommadation_get(student_id) accommodation 
from   students;
```

Where someschema.someschema.f_get_accommadation_get(student_id) is:

```
create or replace function someschema.f_get_accommadation_get(p_student_id in number)
return varchar2 is
local_sped number;

begin
  select sped_cd from someschema.student_sped 
  into local_sped
  where student_id = p_student_id;

  if local_sped = 1 then return('A')
    elsif local_sped = 2 then return('B')
       else        return('C')
    end if;
  end if;
exception when others then return(null);
end;
```

Could I recreate the Oracle function as a UDF, converting the begin...exception...end to begin try and begin catch?

If not, what are my other strategies?

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You are basically right. However, the function will perform like an absolute dog in SQL Server. I'm not sure whether it's any better in Oracle, but I certainly try and avoid scalar functions. For functions in general, you are better off making an inline table function ([second example on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)) and then getting the values using `CROSS APPLY`.

However, in this case, I would almost certainly refactor it to be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with a `CASE` statement ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)).

That would look something like:

```
select student_id,
       CASE spec_cd WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'B'
                    WHEN 3 THEN 'C'
                    ELSE NULL END as ColumnName
from   students s left outer join 
       someschema.student_sped ss 
    on ss.student_id = s.student_id
```